# SQL - Order Data on a Column without including it in ranking

Tags: sql, plsql, amazon-redshift

So I have a scenario where I need to order data on a column without including it in dense_rank(). Here is my sample data set:

This is the table:

```
create table temp
(
id integer,
prod_name varchar(max),
source_system integer,
source_date date,
col1 integer,
col2 integer);
```

This is the dataset:

```
insert into temp
(id,prod_name,source_system,source_date,col1,col2)
values
(1,'ABC',123,'01/01/2021',50,60),

(2,'ABC',123,'01/15/2021',50,60),

(3,'ABC',123,'01/30/2021',40,60),

(4,'ABC',123,'01/30/2021',40,70),

(5,'XYZ',456,'01/10/2021',80,30),

(6,'XYZ',456,'01/12/2021',75,30),

(7,'XYZ',456,'01/20/2021',75,30),

(8,'XYZ',456,'01/20/2021',99,30);
```

Now, I want to do dense_rank() on the data in such a way that for a combination of "prod_name and source_system", the rank gets incremented only if there is a change in col1 or col2 but the data should still be in ascending order of source_date.
Here is the expected result:

| id | prod_name | source_system | source_date | col1 | col2 | Dense_Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 123 | 01-01-21 | 50 | 60 | 1 |
| 2 | ABC | 123 | 15-01-21 | 50 | 60 | 1 |
| 3 | ABC | 123 | 30-01-21 | 40 | 60 | 2 |
| 4 | ABC | 123 | 30-01-21 | 40 | 70 | 3 |
| 5 | XYZ | 456 | 10-01-21 | 80 | 30 | 1 |
| 6 | XYZ | 456 | 12-01-21 | 75 | 30 | 2 |
| 7 | XYZ | 456 | 20-01-21 | 75 | 30 | 2 |
| 8 | XYZ | 456 | 20-01-21 | 99 | 30 | 3 |

As you can see above, the dates are changing but the expectation is that rank should only change if there is any change in either col1 or col2.

If I use this query

```
select id,prod_name,source_system,source_date,col1,col2,
dense_rank() over(partition by prod_name,source_system order by source_date,col1,col2) as rnk
from temp;
```

Then the result would come as:

| id | prod_name | source_system | source_date | col1 | col2 | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 123 | 01-01-21 | 50 | 60 | 1 |
| 2 | ABC | 123 | 15-01-21 | 50 | 60 | 2 |
| 3 | ABC | 123 | 30-01-21 | 40 | 60 | 3 |
| 4 | ABC | 123 | 30-01-21 | 40 | 70 | 4 |
| 5 | XYZ | 456 | 10-01-21 | 80 | 30 | 1 |
| 6 | XYZ | 456 | 12-01-21 | 75 | 30 | 2 |
| 7 | XYZ | 456 | 20-01-21 | 75 | 30 | 3 |
| 8 | XYZ | 456 | 20-01-21 | 99 | 30 | 4 |

And, if I exclude source_date from order by in rank function i.e.

```
select id,prod_name,source_system,source_date,col1,col2,
dense_rank() over(partition by prod_name,source_system order by col1,col2) as rnk
from temp;
```

Then my result is coming as:

| id | prod_name | source_system | source_date | col1 | col2 | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ABC | 123 | 30-01-21 | 40 | 60 | 1 |
| 4 | ABC | 123 | 30-01-21 | 40 | 70 | 2 |
| 1 | ABC | 123 | 01-01-21 | 50 | 60 | 3 |
| 2 | ABC | 123 | 15-01-21 | 50 | 60 | 3 |
| 6 | XYZ | 456 | 12-01-21 | 75 | 30 | 1 |
| 7 | XYZ | 456 | 20-01-21 | 75 | 30 | 1 |
| 5 | XYZ | 456 | 10-01-21 | 80 | 30 | 2 |
| 8 | XYZ | 456 | 20-01-21 | 99 | 30 | 3 |

Both the results are incorrect. How can I get the expected result? Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: I have already tried the query:                                                                                          "select id,prod_name,source_system,date,col1,col2, dense_rank() over(partition by prod_name,source_system order by col1,col2) as rnk from temp order by date;"                                      
                                                                                                                                              This also doesn't work as dense_rank takes precedence in ordering of data.

Comment: Unreadable. Show the dataset as ready-to-use code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Format your queries as a code. Format all outputs as tables. And either MySQL or RedShift, select one of.

Comment: @Akina - I hope its readable now. Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: @RohanKapoor . . . PL/SQL seems to have nothing to do with this question.  The code is not Oracle compatible.  And Oracle has very little to do with Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing multiple columns, I like to look at the previous values of the ordering column, rather than the individual columns.  This makes it much simpler to add more and more columns.

The basic idea is to do a cumulative sum of changes for each prod/source system.  In Redshift, I would phrase this as:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_date = prev_date_2 then 0 else 1 end) over (
            partition by  prod_name, source_system
            order by source_date
            rows between unbounded preceding and current row
           )
from (select t.*,
             lag(source_date) over (partition by prod_name, source_system order by source_date, id) as prev_date,
             lag(source_date) over (partition by prod_name, source_system, col1, col2 order by source_date, id) as prev_date_2
      from temp t
     ) t
order by id;
```

I *think* I have the syntax right for Redshift.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e58f7e50bda881496a8afab95f7a2a03) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.

Note that ties on the date can cause a problem -- regardless of the solution.  This uses the `id` to break the ties.  Perhaps `id` can just be used in general, but your code is using the date, so this uses the date with the id.

Comment: Bang on @Gordon Linoff .. Thanks for this optimized solution. This gives expected result. I have just used 'id' as you suggested.

Comment: @RohanKapoor . . . If this answer your question, you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *,
       LAG(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY prod_name, source_system ORDER BY source_date, id) lag1,
       LAG(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY prod_name, source_system ORDER BY source_date, id) lag2
FROM temp
)
SELECT *,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (col1, col2) = (lag1, lag2)
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1 
                END) OVER (PARTITION BY prod_name, source_system ORDER BY source_date, id) AS `Dense_Rank` 
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac70104c7c5dfb49c75a8635c25716e6

Comment: Thank you for quick revert. I am using redshift DB. Also, this is just a sample dataset which I created. In actual I have 25 columns on which I need to decide whether the rank should be incremented. The data volume is also ~ 90 million. I am taking these factors also in account. So will it be a good idea to have lag for all 25 columns and then comparing them? Is there any other turn around without using CTE?

Comment: @RohanKapoor *In actual I have 25 columns on which I need to decide whether the rank should be incremented. The data volume is also ~ 90 million. I am taking these factors also in account.* Is this task often-performed and performance-critical? if so then think about some virtual generated column which allows to detect the difference and using it in the index (or indexing by an expression if DBMS allows).

Comment: This is first question that I have posted here on this forum. Apologies for tagging my-sql. I removed it after you pointed it in your first comment.

Comment: Is this task often-performed and performance-critical? - Yes this is often performed and the problem is I get Disk Full Error quite often in Redshift with this big dataset.

Comment: @RohanKapoor I do not use RedShift and know it only approximately. Fast documentation searching does not show that generated columns or explicit indexing is possible. So I cannot help you, sorry.

Comment: No worries @Akina. Thank you for your response and time. Really Appreciate it. I have been banging my head on this issue since yesterday. Have tried using lag function and tried building logic to handle this. But still I am missing something. Nonetheless, thank you for your help.